# Aspell dictionary shows up offensive words?

Tags: spell-check, aspell

If you do this in Linux,

```
aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > words
```

it shows up some offensive words like `bitches` etc.

Is there an aspell dictionary list that doesn't contain such offensive words? The other alternative is to remove some words, but that is really cumbersome since there are around 100000 words.

Comment: But aspell checks spelling, not style/context/political correctness, so it doesn't know whether each specific usage is offensive or not. (OED does still define the word as 'female dog'...) Can you at least clarify what level of offensiveness you need to exclude, i.e. where you draw the line?

Comment: @grawity, Right, it even shows up `Mother******` which is the real concern :(. I could have convinced the end users if it was an OED word.

Comment: It is an OED word.

Comment: @JdeBP, yes. Not sure how to go about this problem xD.

Comment: This is insane! Dictionaries and spell-checkers list words which exist. If some people don't like some words is irrelevant, and I sure hope theses people cannot make the words not exist anymore. While spell checkers only correct spelling, dictionaries do explain the meaning and context of words. Would you also want to delete [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherfucker) and many others?

Comment: @mivk agree but some of our end users don't! Convincing them is not easy.

Comment: @Nishant .. such is life in this world. That's the way lexicography works. If a word is used enough it is likely added to the dictionary. if the word is used differently (including wrongly) enough it might also have that meaning (those meanings) added. If you don't like it come up with your own dictionary but to that I say good luck maintaining it. The users are being ridiculous, plain and simple. Maybe they should burn all dictionaries? That's kind of what they're asking you to do.

Comment: Of course you could just filter the 'bad' words out in your pipeline but what happens if a new word gains some offensive meaning? And that's another ridiculous part of their request. The word 'harelip' is considered nowadays as 'offensive' and you should use 'cleft lip'. And eskimo is considered offensive too even though it was based on DISCREDITED etymology. Then there's some words meaning different things in different languages or locales. British English versus American English comes to mind. It's a comical situation when people want a dictionary but are afraid of certain words.

Comment: Indeed, @Pryftan. These are things we have to deal with :-) I mean tough "users".